Helical and Axial Views of CT Scan
As result after a CT scan session, there are helical and axial views of an arm from shoulder to hand and nearby torso with many slices each. I think Siemens Healthineers CT scanner is used. In the dose report DLP is given as 1150 mGycm and CTDI is 15.3. However there is a single scan report submitted although both axial and helical views exist.
I just wonder is this total DLP or for just one of the axial/helical views. How can it be possible to report single CTDI and DLP if both axial and helical views exist? Shouldn't the CTDI values differ at least? I will really appreciate any answers.


How can it be possible to report single CTDI and DLP if both axial and helical views exist?

Because only a single scan was performed.  Scan data were acquired helically, and the axial images (or coronal/sagittal reformats) were reconstructed from it.  There's no such thing as helical views.

Thanks for the clarification. I used wrong words there, there are axial and coronal images.
